# Public headers not finding other public headers

Tags: c++, cmake

I've created a static library using CMake and I'm installing the public headers in /usr/local/include/. The library and its tests compile fine on their own, but when using the library in another project I get an error:

```
/usr/local/include/weftworks/common/network/tcp/acceptor.hpp:28:10: fatal error: utility.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "utility.hpp"
```

where both acceptor.hpp and utility.hpp are public headers.
This is the related folder structure:

```
root/
├ cmake/
├ external/
├ library/
│ ├─ include/
│ │  ├─ network/
│ │  │  └─ tcp/
│ │  │     └─ acceptor.hpp
│ │  └─ utility.hpp
│ ├─ src/
│ └─ CMakeLists.txt
├ test/
└ CMakeLists.txt
```

./library/CMakeLists.txt:

```
# ./library/CMakeLists.txt

# Required CMake version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

include(GNUInstallDirs)

# Project details
project(
        weftworks-common-library
        VERSION         0.4.0
        DESCRIPTION     "Internal Weftworks Common Library project."
)

# Library target sources
list(APPEND WEFTWORKS_COMMON_LIBRARY_PRIVATE_SOURCES)
list(APPEND WEFTWORKS_COMMON_LIBRARY_PUBLIC_SOURCES)
list(APPEND WEFTWORKS_COMMON_LIBRARY_INTERFACE_SOURCES)
include(src/CMakeLists.txt)

# A static library target
add_library(weftworks-common-library STATIC)

# Required compiler features
target_compile_features(
        weftworks-common-library
        PUBLIC
                cxx_auto_type
                cxx_constexpr
                cxx_defaulted_functions
                cxx_deleted_functions
                cxx_final
                cxx_lambdas
                cxx_noexcept
                cxx_override
                cxx_range_for
                cxx_static_assert
                cxx_std_17
                cxx_strong_enums
                cxx_trailing_return_types
                cxx_uniform_initialization
                cxx_variadic_macros
)

target_compile_options(
        weftworks-common-library
        PRIVATE
                -Wall
                -Wextra
                -pedantic
)

target_include_directories(
        weftworks-common-library
        PUBLIC
                "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
                "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>"
)

target_link_libraries(
        weftworks-common-library
        PUBLIC
                Boost::boost
                Boost::system
                Boost::program_options
                spdlog::spdlog
                Threads::Threads
)

target_sources(
        weftworks-common-library
        PUBLIC          ${WEFTWORKS_COMMON_LIBRARY_PUBLIC_SOURCES}
        INTERFACE       ${WEFTWORKS_COMMON_LIBRARY_INTERFACE_SOURCES}
        PRIVATE         ${WEFTWORKS_COMMON_LIBRARY_PRIVATE_SOURCES}
)

# Create alias target
add_library(weftworks::common-library ALIAS weftworks-common-library)

# Install library target
install(
        TARGETS                         weftworks-common-library
        EXPORT                          weftworks-common-library-config
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION             ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION       ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
)

install(
        EXPORT          weftworks-common-library-config
        NAMESPACE       weftworks::
        DESTINATION     ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/weftworks/common-library
)

# Install public headers
install(
        DIRECTORY       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/
        DESTINATION     ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/weftworks/common
)
```

Now I don't know what I need to do to make this work. I'd like to avoid having the "library prefix" in the project structure i.e. `library/include/weftworks/common/` to keep it simple.

Comment: The folder where `utility.hpp` is located needs to be added with `target_include_directories` in the project that uses the library.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, like ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} right? Guess now I need to figure out how to set and export a variable like that. @super

Comment: Yes, with the libraries I use it's usually done using `find_package` and then the `FindXXX.cmake` will then export things like include and linking variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `"weftworks/common/network/utility.hpp"`.

This will also ensure that you actually include your header not some other header which someone has written with the very generic name `"utility.hpp"`.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that then the library itself won't compile anymore unless I create the `library/include/weftworks/common/` structure I mentioned, which I'd like to avoid if possible.